# ViewGroup onLayout in Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to draw a paint palette with paints on top of it. I don't quite understand how the onLayout function works. With my current code I can draw a bunch of little squares in a oval.  But I am not sure how to draw the oval under the squares.

**FingerPaint_Activity**

```
 public class FingerPaint_Activity extends Activity {

  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //This organizes the layout of the different views
    LinearLayout rootLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    rootLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    Paint_Area paintView = new Paint_Area(this);
    rootLayout.addView(paintView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));

    //This is the paint palette object
    Paint_Palette palette = new Paint_Palette(this);
    rootLayout.addView(palette, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
    setContentView(rootLayout);

    for(int splotchIndex = 0; splotchIndex < 6; splotchIndex++)
    {
        View splotchView = new View(this);
        splotchView.setBackgroundColor((0xFF000000) | (int)(Math.random() * 0x00FFFFFF));
        palette.addView(splotchView);
    }
}
}
```

**Paint_Palette**

```
 public class Paint_Palette extends ViewGroup
 {
public Paint_Palette(Context context)
{
    super(context);
}


//Laying out the two views
//The space for the drawing and the part for the palette
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
{
    float splotchWidth = 50.0f;
    float splotchHeight = 50.0f;

    RectF ovalRect = new RectF();
    ovalRect.left = (float)getPaddingLeft() + splotchWidth * 0.5f;
    ovalRect.top = (float)getPaddingTop() + splotchHeight * 0.5f;
    ovalRect.right = (float)(getWidth() - getPaddingRight()) - splotchWidth * 0.5f;
    ovalRect.bottom = (float)(getHeight() - getPaddingBottom()) - splotchHeight * 0.5f;

    for(int splotchIndex = 0; splotchIndex < getChildCount(); splotchIndex++)
    {
        View splotchView = getChildAt(splotchIndex);
        float childTheta = (float)splotchIndex / (float)getChildCount() * 2.0f * (float)Math.PI;
        PointF splotchCenter = new PointF();
        splotchCenter.x = ovalRect.centerX() + ovalRect.width() * 0.5f * (float)Math.cos(childTheta);
        splotchCenter.y = ovalRect.centerY() + ovalRect.height() * 0.5f * (float)Math.sin(childTheta);

        Rect splotcheRect = new Rect();
        splotcheRect.left = (int)(splotchCenter.x - splotchWidth * 0.5f);
        splotcheRect.top = (int)(splotchCenter.y - splotchHeight * 0.5f);
        splotcheRect.right = (int)(splotchCenter.x + splotchWidth * 0.5f);
        splotcheRect.bottom = (int)(splotchCenter.y + splotchHeight * 0.5f);

 splotchView.layout(splotcheRect.left, splotcheRect.top,     splotcheRect.right, splotcheRect.bottom);

    }
}
//Draws the oval
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    Paint ovalPaint = new Paint();
    RectF oval = new RectF(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
    ovalPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#e1af70"));

    canvas.drawOval(oval, ovalPaint);
}

}
```

Could someone please kind of help me understand how onLayout works and how I can draw the children views on top of the main oval view?

Comment: what do you need `onLayout` for? post an image what actually you intend to draw

Comment: Thanks for your response.   I figured it out.  I just had to add the setWillDraw(false) in my onLayout method